# how can i Echo "text" only if attached thumbnail is bigger than "X" resolution in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, echo

can someone please help me out with the following.

how can i Echo "text" only if attached thumbnail resolution is over 500px x 500px in wordpress?

I want to echo a link if the attached thumbnail is bigger than the specified image resolution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found a Solution

```
<?php $imgdata = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'thumbnail' );
                    $imgurl = $imgdata[0]; // the url of the thumbnail picture
                    $imgwidth = $imgdata[1]; // thumbnail's width
                    $imgheight = $imgdata[2]; // thumbnail's height
                    if ($imgwidth >= 200 || $imgheight >= 200){
                        echo 'Success';
                    } else {
                    echo "Nope";
                    }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$size = imagegetsize($image);
if ($size[0] <= 500 || $size[1] <= 500){
  echo "text";
} else {
  echo "<img src=...>"
}
```

Comment: Not working it is breaking the code :(

This is what i have entered in my theme. $img_url is hotlink for full size thumbnail url

<?php $size = imagegetsize($img_url);
if ($size[0] <= 500 || $size[1] <= 500){
echo "success";
} else {
echo "failure"
}
?>